# Eliminating files that are completely contained within other files

Tags: python, python-2.x

I have a block of code that is really bugging me but I can't figure out how to clean it up. I have a list of objects which are all related. In fact some of them are complete supersets of one or more others.

To identify the 'Dupes' which are completely contained within other files, I am comparing every file against every other. Once a file is flagged as a dupe it doesn't need to be included in the comparisons anymore.

The function `isbetter` determines when a file is a superset.

```
for a in self.files:
    if not a.isDupe:
        for b in self.files:                      
            if  a != b and not b.isDupe:
                if a.isbetter(b):
                    b.isDupe = a.name
```

I'm sure there is a very pythonic way to simplify this.

Comment: Perhaps you would also like to include your `isbetter()` function? Also, are we talking about dozens of files? hundreds? And is each file on the order of kilobytes? megabytes?

Comment: I'm certain there should be a more efficient way to do this then my answer below, but it's only worth the complexity if the time complexity is not good (no pun intended).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want to filter out the dupes, so let's apply that to `self.files` first.

```
noDupeFiles = self.files # no dupes at the start, so we initialize it to self.files
for a in noDupeFiles:
    for b in noDupeFiles:
        if a != b and a.isbetter(b):
            b.isDupe = a.name
            # got to remove b once we make it a dupe file
            noDupeFiles.remove(b)
```

This reduces the number of levels from 6 to 4 (since we removed the `not x.isDupe` checks). Next, we combine `for a in noDupeFiles` and `for b in noDupeFiles` with the help of `itertools.permutations`.

```
noDupeFiles = self.files
for a, b in itertools.permutations(noDupeFiles, 2):
    if a != b and a.isbetter(b):
        b.isDupe = a.name
        noDupeFiles.remove(b)
```

This reduces from 4 to 3 levels while keeping the original logic.

---

EDIT:

@marcp pointed out that removing elements from the list apparently threw an exception, so here's the new version:

```
for a, b in itertools.permutations(self.files, 2):
    if not (a.isDupe or b.isDupe) and a.isbetter(b):
        b.isDupe = a.name
```

Comment: @marcp In that case, the filter step is unnecessary. It's safe to remove something from a list while iterating over it -- at least in Python. Also, thanks for pointing out the error.

Comment: oho! itertools.permutations! sweet.

Comment: Actually this doesn't quite work. I've found that I can't remove an item from the list within the loop, it throws an exception but not right away.The working solution is to change the second line of the loop to "if not(a.isDupe or b.isDupe) and a.isbetter(b)"

Comment: @marcp Hmm, looks like I'm mistaken about being able to remove elements in a list. I'll update my answer then -- thanks for letting me know. Also, I realized that I made another error: there's no need to check if `a` is equal to `b`, since the elements are taken without replacement.